# Indent first paragraph only once

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I'm writing a document in English which includes an abstract in Spanish. In Spanish the first paragraph of a chapter should be indented, while in English shouldn't.

If I use `indentfirst` package, all first paragraphs in the document would be indented.

How can I indent a first paragraph only once, i.e., without affecting other first paragraphs in the document?

EDIT: I only want to indent the first line of paragraphs. `\indent` doesn't do the job, maybe because it's overridden to not indent first paragraphs.

Comment: Why not use \indent?

Comment: I think because he wants the whole paragraph to be indeted, not the first line only.

Comment: I want to indent only the first line. \indent doesn't work, I suppose because it's overriden to not indent the first paragraph.

Comment: @Jose In this case you should really edit your question accordingly since it says "How can I indent a first paragraph only once".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\indent` does not work as the code LaTeX inserts to remove the indentation after a section heading really does *remove* the indentation box, even if added explicitly.

Try

```
\section{hhh}
\hspace*{\parindent}aa bb ccaa
```

Answer (score 4):

Add to the code executed when entering Spanish what's done by `indentfirst`; we do also the converse, when exiting Spanish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\let\original@afterindentfalse\@afterindentfalse
\addto{\extrasspanish}{\let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue}
\addto{\noextrasspanish}{\let\@afterindentfalse\original@afterindentfalse}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{spanish}
\section{\abstractname}
\lipsum[2]
\end{otherlanguage}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes +1 for me as no one else had, and this is of course the right way to do it if you have lots of spanish and english sections. If it's just a single abstract though, I thought the hspace was simpler even if it does pollute the document markup a bit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of course: one single indent does not require a complicated solution. I'd be even more drastic: if the base language is English, follow the conventions of English.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a new environment if you would like to indent a full paragraph.

```
\newenvironment{myindentpar}[1]
 {\begin{list}{}
         {\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}}
         \item[]
 }
 {\end{list}}
```

Then you could call this environment by

```
\begin{myindentpar}{3cm}
text text text...
\end{myindentpar}
```

In case you just want to indent a single line I would suggest the `\indent` command.

[Source](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=547)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but yes, I want to indent only the first line. \indent doesn't do the job, maybe because it's overriden to not indent the first paragraph?